# How can I set the shipcarrier to More on a sales order using SuiteScript in a RESTlet?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

SuiteScript v1, but I'll switch to SS v2 if it's the only way to make it work.

I've tried:

```
salesOrder.setFieldText('shipcarrier', 'More');
salesOrder.setFieldValue('shipcarrier', 'noups');
salesOrder.setFieldValue('shipcarrier', 'nonups');
```

But UPS is always selected once the record is saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shipcarrier is a bit of an odd thing.

I'm not sure it is actually sticky - in some contexts it appears to be and in some it doesn't.

It appears to be pointless to set unless you are also setting shipmethod.

```
salesOrder.setFieldValue('shipcarrier', ffShipCarrier); //'ups' || 'nonups'
salesOrder.setFieldValue('shipmethod', ffShipMethod)
```

PS from cja: My conclusion/solution: Setting shipmode does nothing unless recordmode is dynamic and shipmethod is set at the same time. If both those conditions are met then the value shipmode will be updated.

NetSuite support have warned me against using this solution:

"With regards to your concern, I am able to set the Ship carrier field on the Sales Order record in the client script(nlapiSetFieldValue('shipcarrier', 'ups');)  however I was unable to set the value of the field in the server side script. Upon further investigation, the field (ship carrier) isn't exposed in the Record browser hence the field isn't officially exposed for scripting needs. Please refer to the following Suiteanswer article for your reference.

"I am really glad that the solution worked for you perfectly. In order to explain further, I would say it is not advisable to write scripts using unexposed fields in the record browser. It may change in the future without any prior notification and can cause problem and NetSuite will not hold any kind of responsibility for the same.

"User groups contains simple solution to complex tips and tricks provided by the experienced customers. On the other hand, NetSuite Support are stickly adhering to the official documentation/processes to assist any of its customer. The solutions provided in the User groups are totally upto the consent of the customers and can be implemented at their own risk if not confirmed in the official documentation or NetSuite Support."

Comment: I don't have any items in the shipmethod drop down list. Any other way?

Comment: No but if you have no ship methods then why would it matter?

Comment: I have to set shipcarrier to More. shipmethod is unimportant to me but you said that I have to set it in order for my change to shipcarrier to work. But if I have no items in the shipmethod list then I can't set it. That's why it matters.

Comment: I dont think shipmethod is required. I just tried and I was able to save just setting shipcarrier to more with no shipmethod.

Comment: More to the point is : What is the benefit of setting Ship Carrier only? Its purpose is to filter shipping methods. No shipping methods => No need to set Shipping Carrier.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. It's annoying that the web UI lets me set shipcarrier alone but the SS API does.

Comment: My conclusion/solution: Setting shipmode does nothing unless recordmode is dynamic and shipmethod is set at the same time. If both those conditions are met then the value shipmode will be updated.

Comment: This is being investigated by NetSuite as issue 433028

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setFieldValue and pass the internal id of the "More" ship carrier.

```
nlapiSubmitField('salesorder', recordid, 'shipcarrier', 'nonups');
```

Comment: How do I find out what that is? And why wouldn't setFieldText work on this occasion?

Comment: Maybe you are not saving the record. This worked on my end: nlapiSubmitField('salesorder', recordid, 'shipcarrier', 'nonups');

Comment: I am creating the record so I know I'm saving it. I think your code is client side and so will not work in my RESTlet.

Comment: That code runs fine serverside too. Once you have created the record try setting the carrier with the code I posted.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. No error, just nothing happens.

Comment: In that case add some debug logging at the beginning and see if the RESTlet is being executed at all.

Comment: It is being executed because, as I said above, the RESTlet is creating the sales order. If it was not being executed then the record would not be created at all. I have a solution now. Thank you for your efforts to assist me.